# Request method GETS Zero value

Tags: php, .htaccess, curl

Hi i am trying to get the request method when the URL is requested from my localhost. I have done URL rewriting so that http://localhost/API2/products.php?product_id=1 becomes http://localhost/API2/products.php/products/1 as a result $request_method=$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]; should hold GET as the method. But rather it gets zero every time.

my.htaccess file holds these url rules:

```
      RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine
      RewriteRule ^products/?$ products.php [NC,L]
      RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)/?$ products.php?product_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

My curl commands in learn.php are:

```
   <?php
    $url = 'http://localhost/API2/products';
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response_json = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $response=json_decode($response_json, true);

   ?>
```

So when i run my curl command which is learn.php neither it presents me any data because $request_method=$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] the request method is holding zero value.

Comment: Your question says from *product.php?product_id=1* to *products/1*, yet your redirection code does the opposite...?  Anyway, $_GET will only include values if the URL is in the form ?key=value.  On a /page/key/value, $_GET will not have anything.

Comment: No the issue is when i run my curl commands which are in learn.php file it doesnot get into the switch case for instance if its POST post case should be run which shows request_method is not getting right value.

Comment: or i guess my curl request is not getting executed. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Add that to disable MultiViews:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

The [Apache docs on mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html), describes what the Multiviews Option does, when enabled:

> If the
>   server receives a request for /some/dir/foo and /some/dir/foo does not
>   exist, then the server reads the directory looking for all files named
>   foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those
>   files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it
>   would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then
>   chooses the best match to the client's requirements, and returns that
>   document.

Use:

```
# disable products -> products.php
Options -MultiViews
# Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/?$ products.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)/?$ products.php?product_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: This doen't work rather it gives internal server error when i try to run any php file from my repository. The problem is that curl command is not getting executed which means  server_request method doesnot hold GET,POST,PUT OR DELETE. So if you could help in that.

Comment: Because mod_negotiation (ie. MultiViews) processes the URL before mod_rewrite.

Comment: Clear your cache or try with other browser !

Comment: IT doesnot work. The problem is i am retrieving data from curl command which means its a GET method. In my other products .php file i am not able to get $request_method=$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]; so that i can return data depending upon request type using switch case. Kindly look into url rewriting as well. Thanks