# Curl command not getting executed

Tags: php, .htaccess, curl

I am trying to run curl command from php script But its not working as expected. Either the issue is in curl command or in my url rewriting rules written in .htacccess file.

code in curl command file: i am simply trying to post data using this command and expecting an array to be returned.

```
    <?php
     $data=array(
    'product_name' =>'Television',
    'price' => 1000,
    'quantity' => 10,
    'seller' =>'XYZ Traders'
   );
   $url = 'http://localhost/API2/products';
    $ch = curl_init($url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   $response_json = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   $response=json_decode($response_json, true);
   echo $response;

  ?>
```

My .htaccess file is used for url rewritng which means http://localhost/API2/products should be used for CRUD operations. The url rules are:

```
  RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine
  RewriteRule ^products/?$ products.php [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)/?$ products.php?product_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

So if you could help in finding the issue as when i run the curl command file.php it doen't return anything nor does it execute the code.

Comment: What's in $response_json? Have you tried to echo that?

Comment: $request_method=$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
    
 switch($request_method)
 {

  case 'POST':
  $response=array(
    'status' => 1,
    'status_message' =>'Product Added Successfully.'
   );
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($response);

   default:
   // Invalid Request Method
   header("HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed");
   break;
 }

Comment: i don't get what you want with this comment man

Comment: its like this in my other file. I edited it. I use switch statement depending upon the request_method it needs to get into it and return the array.

Comment: The point is that you have to check the raw response from curl and check what's inside before using json_decode

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47074446/request-method-gets-zero-value

Comment: connectedPosting data{"status":0,"status_message":"Product Addition Failed."} i get this rather it should go into POST and return the post array

Comment: well data is being posted using curl how to receive it in PHP file? simply by using S_POST ? as you can see i am sending data array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are attempting to POST an array ($data), when you should be POSTing a string.

To fix this, add the function URLify below.

```
function URLify( $arr, $encode = FALSE ) {

    $fields_string = '';
    foreach( $arr as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $encode ) {
      $key = urlencode( $key );
            $value = urlencode( $value );
        }
        $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
    }
    $fields_string = substr( $fields_string, 0, (strlen($fields_string)-1) );

    return $fields_string;

}
```

Then add:

```
$data = URLify( $data, TRUE );
```

above:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/API2/products';
```

Comment: How do i receive the data on products.php when data is posted from curl. I am trying to get using $_POST . Like this:    echo"Got here ";
  $_product_name=$_POST["product_name"];
  $_price=$_POST["price"];
  $_quantity=$_POST["quantity"];
  $_seller=$_POST["seller"];
  echo"data:= "+$_product_name+$_price+$_quantity+$_seller;

Comment: @Rahila It's important not to ask additional questions in the comments area. The answer I provided is the answer to the question you asked. Please mark it as the correct answer and then add your new question as a question on StackOverflow. If you post a link to your new question here I'll take a shot at answering it.

Comment: thanks for telling me that it works but if you could just tell how do i receive the data and unpack . i am trying $_POST to get the data from url but it gets 1's and zero's. thanks

Comment: @Rahila You don't get data from the URL using $_POST. That's done using $_GET. If you post your code in a new question, it'll be a lot easier to help.

Comment: @Rahila Regarding the code posted above... you're going to have a problem because you're attempting to echo the array $response. To echo an array, use something like echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $response );
    echo '</pre>';

Comment: if you could look into this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47084000/unpack-data-sent-using-post-curl  thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158109/discussion-between-ben-shoval-and-rahila).